# Decrypting the DUKPT TDES encrypted code of a Magnetic stripe reader in C#?

Tags: c#

I am developing application for Magnetic Stripe reader, and the encrypted code format is DUKPT TDES Algorithm so my question is,

```
 How to decrypt the encrypted code using DUKPT-TDES alogorithm in C#?
```

if any sample library available please post here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_unique_key_per_transaction), DUKPT is a Key Management method or process for assigning a unique Key for encryption of each transaction to be encrypted. As such it is not an encryption method, just a way of getting the key to use in the encryption (in your case the encryption method is Triple DES).

You will either have to make your own process for DUKPT, or find out how to use the process of the appropriate provider. Using your own should be OK (but not a trivial task, I guess) unless someone other than you needs to be able to decrypt the encrypted data: they will then need a way of getting hold of the correct key.

Comment: Thanks simon,  I got sample library and modified that with my requirement and worked fine..

Comment: Where did you find this library? I need to port something to Java?

Comment: I've no idea what he found, but this might be a start: http://thalessim.codeplex.com/discussions/214171

Comment: @bailey .   Found in github .